# What are _UPVALUE0_ keywords in decompiled Lua?

Tags: lua, decompiling

I have decompiled a few lua codes, was able to understand most of them.

But there are these *UPVALUE0*, *UPVALUE1*, etc... keywords I see in the code that are not defined anywhere as far as I've looked.

Here's an example:

```
local L0_0
L0_0 = module
L0_0((...), package.seeall)
function L0_0(A0_1)
  if A0_1 - math.floor(A0_1) > 0 then
    error("trying to use bitwise operation on non-integer!")
  end
end
bit = {
    bxor = function(A0_17, A1_18)
    local L2_19, L3_20, L4_21, L5_22
    L2_19 = _UPVALUE0_
    L3_20 = A0_17
    L2_19 = L2_19(L3_20)
    L3_20 = _UPVALUE0_
    L4_21 = A1_18
    L3_20 = L3_20(L4_21)
    L4_21 = _UPVALUE1_
    L5_22 = L2_19
    L4_21(L5_22, L3_20)
    L4_21 = {}
    L5_22 = math
    L5_22 = L5_22.max
    L5_22 = L5_22(table.getn(L2_19), table.getn(L3_20))
    for _FORV_9_ = 1, L5_22 do
      if L2_19[_FORV_9_] ~= L3_20[_FORV_9_] then
        L4_21[_FORV_9_] = 1
      else
        L4_21[_FORV_9_] = 0
      end
    end
    return _UPVALUE2_(L4_21)
    end
}
```

What do they mean?

Comment: Your script is the body of a function (which was `string.dump`ed and then decompiled).  The variables `_UPVALUE0_`, `_UPVALUE1_` and `_UPVALUE2_` are local variables defined outside the function.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There are like 600 files, I don't know how to look for the right variables that hold the value for _UPVALUEX_.

Comment: When a separate function is dumped, the information about where its upvalues defined is lost.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I was able to track a similar code on the internet, http://valentin.dasdeck.com/lingo/lsw/editor_lingo_support/SciTE/SciTELingoIDE/lua_backend/bit.lua , do you think these are both the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html:

> .. is neither a global variable nor a local variable. We call it an
>   external local variable, or an upvalue. (The term "upvalue" is a
>   little misleading, because it is a variable, not a value. However,
>   this term has historical roots in Lua and it is shorter than "external
>   local variable".)

```lua
local i = 0
function inc()
  i = i + 1
  return i
end
```

Variable `i` in function `inc` is **upvalue**, as it is not local variable in this function and not global variable.

Comment: I have updated the code in question, there's only one variable before the function, but inside the function there's another upvalue `_UPVALUE1_`. So there had to be 2 variables before the function for UPVALUE1 to work. That's confusing me

Comment: If it is your full source, than function `bxor` is assigned from another module like `bit.bxor = internal.bxor` and then used `string.dump`. Reading from your code `_UPVALUE0_` should be the function which converts number to table filled with numbers-bits, `_UPVALUE2_` should be the function which converts table filled with number-bits to number.